# Alt + Tab panel gets hidden behind other windows

Tags: windows-7

In Win 7 Enterprise 64-bit version, a strange problem has started to give me problems.

When switching between applications, the panel that shows running apps (while holding the Alt-key) gets hidden behind the preview window. Anyone have had that problem and solved it?

Answer (score 1):

either uninstall IE9 or disable all of desktop gadgets. After uninstalling IE9 everything was ok again on my PC. BTW: is is not only on 64 bis OS.